# Realtime monitoring using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to monitor some network devices using Django.
Lets say I have three PC in three different locations.

```
PC1= city1
PC2= city2
PC3= city3
```

Something like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byRj4.png)

what is the best way to make a realtime monitoring application in Django.

I already know that I can use snmp or ping to get the status of these PC's. (using views). And I know a bit about mapbox or Java to get an interactive map.

So! how can I have a webpage that automatically update the status of these PC's for example every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to do this. The first is a page with some JS that has a [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) code which runs every 10 seconds, this timeout will do an ajax call to your server which will execute your "get status" commands and returns a JSON result which you can update the data on your browser page with.

The other solution is to have an open websocket with your server, and then have a a [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html) worker which runs a periodic task every 10 seconds that executes your "get status" commands and returns the result to your open websocket(s) which then updates your browser page.

Hope this helps!